# How to remove duplicate records from Huge csv file and store it into Database in Mulesoft using Anypoint Studio

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Suppose I have a huge CSV files say it contains 10000 records and it has 3 fields say ID, Name and Age and it also has some duplicate records. Here I want to remove duplicate records based on ID field and store the all the unique records in Database.
How should I achieve it in Mulesoft using Anypoint Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dataweave to identify unique records. And then insert intoDB.

Flow will be like `File Connector(Reading File) >> Dataweave(identify unique records) >> DB connector(DB insert)`.

Please refer this for more details.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#distinct-by

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the distinct option in dataweave and create an output as csv format file itself.

Check the link below for distinct operator.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-operators#distinct-by